# Keycloak's Spring Boot adapter with Jetty causing seemingly unrelated exceptions

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty, keycloak

I'm experiencing an issue whilst trying to secure a small Jetty-based Spring Boot application using Keycloak.

I'm following [this](http://slackspace.de/articles/authentication-with-spring-boot-angularjs-and-keycloak/) tutorial for the backend part (skipping the Angular-specific bits), but as soon as I include the `keycloak-spring-boot-adapter` my application does not start and throws a couple of seemingly unrelated stacktraces. From the stacktraces it seems the autoconfiguration cannot resolve the `ServletContext` for some unknown reason.

I've created a stripped down sample of my application with which I'm able to reproduce the issue. It can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/bdalenoord/keycloak-spring-boot-issue). Clean cloning the repo and calling `mvn clean package && java -jar target/api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` results in the stacktrace found in the README.

Has anyone got an idea why adding the dependency borks up my autoconfiguration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a bug in the `keycloak-spring-boot-adapter`, for which I've now filed a bugreport and pull request.

[Bugreport](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-3807)
[PR](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/3420)

The pull request hasn't been merged at the time of writing, but it should be soon.